Finite group with specific cohomological properties
I would like to find an example of a finite group $G$ with the following property:
Let me write $N\subseteq H^2(G;\mathbb{F}_2)$ for the $\mathbb{F}_2$-subspace consisting of those classes $x$ whose square $x\cup x$ is zero in $H^4(G;\mathbb{F}_2)$. Let $n$ be the dimension of $N$. Let me also write $m$ for the dimension of $H^6(G;\mathbb{Z})\otimes \mathbb{F}_2$.
What is an example of a finite group $G$ for which $n>m$??
For instance, taking $G=Q_8$ the quaternions, we have $n=m=2$, but I would like to have an example with a sharp inequality!
